# java unknown protocol: e when downloading a file

Tags: java, file, url, download

I'm a beginner to java file handling. I tired to get a bin file (en-parser-chunking.bin) from my hard disk partition to my web application. So far I have tried below code and it gives me the output in my console below.

> unknown protocol: e

these are the code samples I have tried so far

```
//download file
public void download(String url, File destination) throws IOException {
    URL website = new URL(url);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}




public void parserAction() throws Exception {
    //InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
    File modelFile = new File("en-parser-chunking.bin");

    if (!modelFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Downloading model.");
        download("E:\\Final Project\\Softwares and tools\\en-parser-chunking.bin", modelFile);
    }


    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(modelFile);
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
    for (Parse p : topParses){
        //p.show();
        getNounPhrases(p);
    }
}
```

getting a file in this way is possible or I have done it wrong ?

note - I need to get this from my hard disk. not download from the internet

Answer (score 2):

the correct URL for a local file is:

```
file://E:/Final Project/Softwares and tools/en-parser-chunking.bin
```

where `file` is the protocol.

You can also you:

```
new File("E:/Final Project/Softwares and tools/en-parser-chunking.bin").toURL()
```

to create a URL from your file.

I also recomment to use slash as file seperator instead of backslash

Comment: this gives me below output     " Downloading model.
Connection timed out: connect"